# Send mail to Outlook group via ANT

Tags: ant, outlook, sendmail

I would like to send automated emails to outlook groups using ANT scripts.

Using ANT's `mail task` to send to receipients separatd by comma and it works fine.

Is there any way how to send mails to Outlook group via `ANT tasks`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added SSL="false" for the ANT task, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

The ant [mail task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html) works the same way - whether it is individual email or group email. So long as the email-id of the Outlook group is specified in the same way as individual recipients, it should work.

Do note that the Outlook group as visible in Outlook is often not the same as the email-id.  For instance `Production Support` could be the display name in Outlook, but the email-id could be `product-support@myorg.com`.